# AER device [15b7:5006] error on Ubuntu 20.04 and Intel SpeedStep Technology

Tags: boot, lenovo, intel

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad E15 whith Ubuntu 20.04 mounted on a NVMe SSD 1TB, in dual boot with the original Windows 10 Pro, and everything went well.
I added some software and external hardware. Now I have this error during the boot with Ubuntu:
AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=corrected type=Physical layer (receveir id)
AER: device [15b7:5006] error status /mask=00...01/0000e000
AER [0] RxERR
and the Ubuntu's boot is possible only with Ubuntu's recovery mode.

Instead, Windows 10 Pro, built in from Lenovo, starts normally.
At the same time of the error, during the boot of Ubuntu, the cooling fan is on, in the coldest month of the year.

I tried, according to the community
https://itsfoss.com/pcie-bus-error-severity-corrected/
these steps:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
I edit grub adding in the line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
in the end of the line: 
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=noaer"     #or
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=nomsi"     #or
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=off" #or
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=nommconf"
sudo update-grub
Reboot now
```

but no one of these changes of the grub works for me.
I don't understand the meaning and the function of these commands added.
According to https://80.87.195.87/index.php?id=pci:15b7-5006-15b7-5006 I realized that [15b7:5006] is the device: 'Sandisk WD Black SN750 / PC SN730 NVMe SSD'
and (from the same link) that the same error "AER: device [15b7:5006]" was advertised in some computer.

Two facts:

1. the fan starting up at the boot and
2. the indication of the NVMe SSD

have led me to
switch off in the setup of the computer Lenovo E15 the Intel SpeedStep Technology:
SETUP>CONFIG>POWER>Intel SpeedStep Technology> [On]-->Off
and so, the error disappears and the boot of Ubuntu 20.04 go normally.

It follows, from all this, that there is a partial incompatibility between
Intel SpeedStep Technology and Ubuntu 20.04
here resolved with the switch off in the setup of the Intel SpeedStep Technology,
so that the community knows an incompatibility and a practical solution found.

Is there a direct solution in the configuration of Ubuntu so that I can continue to use Intel SpeedStep in Lenovo E15 without Ubuntu's recovery mode at every boot?

Comment: Did you try and google Intel speed step and Ubuntu? I just did and all the info is quite old back in 14.04 days but thy all say the same thing that it does not play well with Ubuntu. Maybe take a look at some of them?

Comment: Thank you sir, I’ll take a full look.

Answer (score 1):

First af all, following the directions of David, according to
https://superuser.com/questions/454101/is-there-a-way-to-disable-intel-speedstep-steppings-on-an-ubuntu-server-using-a
I used these commands to read and change the status of the cpufreq's gestion in Ubuntu:

to reading the current available settings for your system:
sudo cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors

to set each core to performance mode:
sudo echo performance > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor

to check if the option was successfully changed:
sudo cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor

to install cpufreq-info:
sudo apt-get install cpufrequtils

to check and get information about the current frequency:
cpufreq-info

Therefore I have found in my Lenovo E15 performance and powersave as "*available settings*":

```
sudo cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors
performance powersave
```

I check the status after switch off the Intel SpeedStep Technology in the setup of the computer and I got "*powersave*":

```
sudo cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor
powersave
```

I tried to change the status in performance, but I obtained a "*permission denied*":

```
sudo echo performance > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor  
bash: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor: permission denied
```

Therefore, I think, in Ubuntu 20.04 on Lenovo E15, superuser can't change the status of the cpufreq's scaling_governor

After excluding in the setup the Intel SpeedStep, I executed the commands:
cat /proc/cpuinfo
lscpu
cpufreq-info
to know the CPU's frequency status:

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0  
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel  
cpu family  : 6  
model       : 142  
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10510U CPU @ 1.80GHz  
stepping    : 12  
microcode   : 0xde  
cpu MHz: 700.064


$ lscpu
Architecture:    x86_64  
CPU op-mode(s):  32-bit, 64-bit  
Byte Order:      Little Endian  
Address sizes:   39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual  
CPU(s):          8  
Model name:      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10510U CPU @ 1.80GHz  
Stepping:        12  
CPU MHz:         600.317  
CPU max MHz:     1800,0000  
CPU min MHz:     400,0000


$ cpufreq-info
bounds hardware:    400 MHz - 1.80 GHz  
available settings: performance, powersave  
current governor:   frequency must be between 400 MHz and 1.80 GHz  
governor "powersave" can decide which speed to use. in this range.  
CPU's current frequency is 1.80 GHz.
```

**I switched in the setup of the computer:**
**SpeedStep=OFF** and **CPU power manag.= ON** and then: **Ubuntu boots OK**
**SpeedStep= ON** and **CPU power manag.= ON** and then: **Ubuntu boots only in recovery mode**
**SpeedStep= ON** and **CPU power manag.=OFF** and then: **Ubuntu boots randomly**

I googled "*Intel speed step and Ubuntu*" and below follow the results:

- http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man4/est.4freebsd.html  says: "the est (Enhanced Speedstep Technology) capabilities are
  automatically loaded by the cpufreq driver";
- https://www.intel.it/content/www/it/it/support/articles/000007073/processors.html
  gives brief explanations about the Intel SpeedStep Technology;
- other pages are all about "*Ubuntu run slowly*" and "*Ubuntu's
  performances*".

But the most important page seems to me to be:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_frequency_scaling
it explains with clarity and completeness the CPU frequency scaling and the troubleshooting.
Especially for the IBM/Lenovo Thinkpads refers to thinkwiki for more thinkpad related info on this topic:
http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Problem_with_CPU_frequency_scaling
This page at the end says:

> Add "processor.ignore_ppc=1" to kernel boot command line or run
> $ echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/module/processor/parameters/ignore_ppc
> This allows to disable BIOS frequency limit, but can be cause the computer to malfunction if its power consumption is higher than 65W and you are running off a 65W AC power adapter with no battery installed.

In conclusion, I can't risk leading to malfunction the computer changing CPU's parameters, because my job doesn’t allow it.
**I prefer, without changing the CPU's parameters in Ubuntu, to leave Intel SpeedStep *off* in the setup of the Lenovo E15: this allows a normal boot of Ubuntu 20.04.**

Thank you David, for your directions and your prompt response!

Comment: Not sure if this could be relevant, but I had this problem: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=203183#c41